# Change height of NavBar in Navigation Controller in Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, uinavigationbar

I cannot figure this out for the life of me. Apple really wants you to keep it at 44 points apparently. I've figured out how to change the colors, fonts, etc... But wondering if I can do a custom height.

So far I've gotten this, but it doesn't change anything:

```
UINavigationBar *navbar= [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
[navbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
```

Any suggestions would be amazing if someone knows how to do this.

Comment: Eeek, you might be SOL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590691/how-do-i-change-the-uinavigationbars-height?rq=1

Comment: Before you give up, try using constraints instead of frame; this thing might have an intrinsic size. (That is just a pure guess; I have not tried it.)

Comment: I don't think iOS allows you to customize the height of the navigation bar. You need to hide it and create a custom view that mimics the behavior if you absolutely want that.

Comment: Thank you, it seems as if you're probably right Taum!